# url construction htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, construction

Lets say I have a link to one of my page that looks like: mysite.com/48YSWD96, I need it to look like: mysite.com/?d=48YSWD96. How do I achieve this? Can I achieve this by modifying my htaccess file? which currently looks like this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to append this to the end:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

For it to work the other way around:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([A-Za-z0-9]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1 [L]
```

This will take a request for `mysite.com/?d=48YSWD96` and change the URI to `/48YSWD96`. Essentially, whatever the **id** equals in the query string.

Comment: ehhhh, that just takes me to the index of the root folder. any other suggestions?

Comment: That takes `mysite.com/48YSWD96` and rewrites to `mysite.com/?d=48YSWD96`, which is what you asked. Can you clarify what it is you want?

Comment: well that's exactly what I want... by 'append to the end', does that mean take that piece of code you wrote and place it in exactly after the last rewrite rule I have in my initial htaccess that I posted & before the Rewrite Base/, or do I have to put it somewhere else? I really appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: If your htaccess file is in your document root, it doesn't matter if it's before or after. Note that `mysite.com/?d=48YSWD96` is the index of the root folder with a query string (d=48YSWD96).

Comment: Jon, that just doesn't work. with your addition to my htaccess, actually regardless of it, if I type in mysite.com/?d=48YSWD96, it just take me to a white index page with links on it. I need it to take me to mysite.com/48YSWD96. s'gotta be something you're not telling me

Comment: Forget it, you don't have the answer. I still need help if anyone's lurking.