# mod-rewrite force ?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to be able to post links that look like "mysite.com/?d=48YSWD96" & go to file path "/d=48YSWD96.php" So, I need "mysite.com/?d=48YSWD96" to go to "mysite.com/d=48YSWD96". I can't start my file name with a "?" because it will just turn into an index page for the root folder and disregard the content in the file. How do I do this? this is my htacces:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess mod force extra characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461824/htaccess-mod-force-extra-characters)

Comment: please tell us precisely what should the user type in his browser, and what should be the final, modified URL on the server side **after** rewriterules applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing as the query string match from this question (which has the same .htaccess): [url construction htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454122/url-construction-htaccess/8454563#8454563)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)d=([A-Za-z0-9]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /d=%2.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm not expert, but it looks as if you completely diregarded the '?' in the cond/rule you gave me. I need to be able to use the '?' for my links. 'd=' doesnt need any rewrite, i can just start a file name with that

Comment: Sorry, had the wrong backreferece. The %{QUERY_STRING} variable doesn't include the **?** part, just the parameters and the **&** that separate them.